# Keyboard Tab focus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

I am using file-input with Jasny bootstrap. Everything is fine except in Keyboard Tab focus Field is not highlighting. Please provide me a solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you have to do: make the "buttons" (they are spans) focusable and bind `keypress` event to click on hidden input.
I'm really bad with javascript, so this could be done better, but it works for me at the moment:

```
  $('.fileinput .btn').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('tabindex') === undefined) { // if it hasn't tabindex
      $(this).attr('tabindex', 0);
    }
    $(this).on('keypress', function(e){
      if ( e.which == 13 ) { // only works with enter key
        $(this).children('input').click();
      }
    });
  });
```

please fix my english and my code, I use them to work :D